# IMG tags not working, but background-image working

Tags: angular, image, tags, background-image

I'm using Angular 14 and ASP.NET 6
background-image working but img tag not working. How can I solve this problem?

**BankSearch.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="res/hand.png" alt="hand" width="200"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

**BankSearch.css**

```
body {
    background-image:url("res/hand.png");
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
  background-size:auto;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using Angular 14 and actually this problem coming from Angular. Angular looking assets/ folder for  source.
I solved this problem like this; I moved my res folder to assets folder. My working code:

```
<img class="handimg" src="../../assets/res/hand.png" alt="hand" />
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but it's **not** correct. Use `src="assets/res/hand.png"` or `src="/assets/res/hand.png"`. Think that Angular when build create in a directory "dist" the index.html, the bundles (the .js) and a folder "assets" (copy of your assets folder) -when use ng-server imagine some similar but in another directory-. So **from** your index.html, "hand.png" is in `assets/res` folder

Comment: A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbdrtu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) using assets folder in case of load data, src of img tag and in background-image: url(); NOTE: the difference between use "/assets/..." (absolute) and "assets/..." (relative) is related to when you use a base href diferent than `/` or `./`